# Stanford NLP sentiment score returns -1 always in c#

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to implement Stanford NLP sentiment analysis code in c# using code borrowed from this site and on the main Stanford website. The following code works but Score is always -1. Score should be between 0 to 4. Any help?

```
    // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
    var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
    var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);

    foreach(String text in texts) {   
        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);

        // these are all the sentences in this document
        // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
        var sentences = document.get(new CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation().getClass()) as ArrayList;

        String[] sentimentText = { "Very Negative","Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Very Positive"};

        foreach(CoreMap sentence in sentences) {
            Tree tree = (Tree)sentence.get(typeof(edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation));
            int score = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
            Console.WriteLine(sentimentText[score]);  // prints sentiment for each sentence in the doc

        }
```

Comment: Seriously? You think this is an answerable question? The only mention of `score` is `int score = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);` That method obviously returns -1 but without that code how can we even guess why?

Comment: Share code of `RNNCoreAnnotations` class.

Comment: If you read the docs for RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(), it tells you why it returns -1: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/neural/rnn/RNNCoreAnnotations.html#getPredictedClass-edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree-

Comment: This should not be downvoted! It's entirely answerable and it was helpful to me - you just have to understand the stanford-nlp project. Ibexy's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

change:

```
Tree tree = (Tree)sentence.get(typeof(edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation));
```

to:

```
Tree tree = (Tree)sentence.get(typeof(edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree));
```